# Does MySQL have problems with nested insert like with subqueries in where?

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

Query 1:

```
INSERT `personal`.`locations` 
  SELECT DISTINCT `s`.* 
    FROM `references` `t`
      JOIN `locations` `s` ON `first_id` = `s`.`id` 
    WHERE 
      `lat` >= 37.3
      AND `lat` <= 37.3
      AND `lng` >= -122.2 
      AND `lng` <= -122.1 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  `lat`  = `s`.`lat`,
  `lng`  = `s`.`lng`,
  `name` = `s`.`name`,
  `desr` = `s`.`desr`;
```

Query 2:

```
INSERT `personal`.`locations` 
  SELECT DISTINCT `s`.* 
    FROM `references` `t`
      JOIN `locations` `s` ON (`first_id` = `s`.`id` OR `second_id` = `s`.`id`) 
    WHERE 
      `lat` >= 37.3
      AND `lat` <= 37.3
      AND `lng` >= -122.2 
      AND `lng` <= -122.1 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  `lat`  = `s`.`lat`,
  `lng`  = `s`.`lng`,
  `name` = `s`.`name`,
  `desr` = `s`.`desr`;
```

---

The select in query 1 takes 0.008 seconds to select 4 million records.

The select in query 2 takes 1 second to select 300 thousand records.

Query 1 executes completely in 60 seconds.

Query 2 executes completely in 300 seconds.

The conclusion: MySQL seems to repeat the select for every insert just like with where clause subqueries.

**Is there a solution?**

---

**Edit 1:** Added new query

Query 2: faster alternative but still with the same issue

```
INSERT `personal`.`locations` 
  SELECT DISTINCT `s`.* 
    FROM `references` `t`
      JOIN `locations` `s` ON `first_id` = `s`.`id` 
    WHERE 
      `lat` >= 37.3
      AND `lat` <= 37.3
      AND `lng` >= -122.2 
      AND `lng` <= -122.1 
UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT `s`.* 
    FROM `references` `t`
      JOIN `locations` `s` ON `second_id` = `s`.`id` 
    WHERE 
      `lat` >= 37.3
      AND `lat` <= 37.3
      AND `lng` >= -122.2 
      AND `lng` <= -122.1 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  `lat`  = `s`.`lat`,
  `lng`  = `s`.`lng`,
  `name` = `s`.`name`,
  `desr` = `s`.`desr`;
```

Slightly faster despite the fact it actually executes more updates but since the two selects execute faster the the one they replace it gains a bit of time.

---

**Edit 2:** Added table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `references` (
  `id`        bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_id`  bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `second_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name`      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status`    enum('V','I','D') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'V',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `first_id`  (`first_id`),
  KEY `second_id` (`second_id`),
  KEY `status`    (`status`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locations` (
  `id`        bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lat`       double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lng`       double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name`      varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `desr`      varchar(254) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status`    enum('V','I','D') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'V',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `lat`    (`lat`),
  KEY `lng`    (`lng`)
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Each reference has to have at least one location associated based on first_id. The second is optional but it does exist for 70%-80% of the records. Each location can be associated with multiple references.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the table definitions for the two tables (including indexes)? Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's a coincidence but whenever I see `DISTINCT` in a (sub)query with more than a thousand rows, it's a design problem.

Comment: Are there 2 `locations` tables (in different databases) or one?

Comment: Yes there are 2 identical in different databases. Data is copied from one to another.

Comment: how long would it take to just join on the second_id? `JOIN \`locations\` \`s\` ON \`second_id\` = \`s\`.\`id\` `

Comment: and does the table `locations` have an entry with the `id` 0?

Comment: For each location there is at least one reference but usually more then one. Second id is the previous location id if there was one for the user in the current session. So most of the time second id holds something except for the first references attached to the first location in a session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `OR` in the `JOIN` part of your query results in the query to be performed for **all 4 million records** returned from the result set of the left hand side OR clause.

So using a solution with `UNION` is definitely faster.